# How to access an array in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, object

I have the following JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "comments": [
            {
                "created_at": "2011-02-09T14:42:42-08:00",
                "thumb": "xxxxxxx",
                "level": 1,
                "id": 214,
                "user_id": 41,
                "parent_id": 213,
                "content": "<p>xxxxxx</p>",
                "full_name": "xx K"
            },
            {
                "created_at": "2011-02-09T14:41:23-08:00",
                "thumb": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "level": 0,
                "id": 213,
                "user_id": 19,
                "parent_id": null,
                "content": "<p>this is another test</p>",
                "full_name": "asd asd asd asd asd"
            }
        ],
        "eee1": "asdadsdas",
        "eee2": "bbbbb"
    }
]
```

This is coming from a `$.ajax` request, in success I have....

```js
success: function (dataJS) {
    console.log(dataJS);
    console.log(dataJS[eee1]);
    console.log(dataJS.comments);
}
```

Problem is I can't get access to the items in the JSON object, even though dataJS does show correctly in the console. Ideas?

Comment: console.log(dataJS.comments[0]); ?

Comment: Have you checked that the Content-Type of the response headers really are application/json?

Comment: @Anapprentice Could you please respond to the thread with the correct answer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because your base object is an array as well.

```
console.log(dataJS[0].comments[0]);
```

I suspect that would work

Answer (score 6):

the JSON you have coming back is actually an array itself, so...

```
dataJS[0].comments[0].created_at
```

will be `2011-02-09T14:42:42-08:00`, etc...

Both `dataJS` and `comments` are arrays, and need indexes to access the appropriate elements.

Comment: No, it isn't built out of spec so no it's not 'incorrect', but what syntax are you wanting to use to access it?

Comment: ok that's all I needed to know. Thank you! I will accept once stackoverflow lets me...

Answer (score 3):

The object being returned is itself an array, so to get to the first comment (as an example), this is how you would access it:

`dataJS[0].comments[0]`

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(dataJS);
console.log(dataJS[0].eee1);
console.log(dataJS[0].comments[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:-

```
var dataJS = [{"comments":[{"created_at":"2011-02-09T14:42:42-08:00","thumb":"xxxxxxx","level":1,"id":214,"user_id":41,"parent_id":213,"content":"<p>xxxxxx</p>","full_name":"xx K"},{"created_at":"2011-02-09T14:41:23-08:00","thumb":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx","level":0,"id":213,"user_id":19,"parent_id":null,"content":"<p>this is another test</p>","full_name":"asd asd asd asd asd"}],"eee1":"asdadsdas","eee2":"bbbbb"}];

var created_at = dataJS[0].comments[0].created_at;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as others have stated, the JSON is actually an Array (of a single Object).  So you will need to reference an index.

Interestingly enough (to me), your result string does validate successfully as JSON.  I assumed until now, that to be valid JSON, it had to be an Object (ie, {}).

Answer (score -3):

JSON must be interpreted with `eval` function (after the obvious sanitization, see security considerations of eval). Are you sure your framework does that for you?

Comment: Yes, jQuery evaluates the JSON.

Comment: implied by `$.ajax` and the jquery tag

Comment: I guessed $.ajax can be any framework, like $ is used generally by most of them $.ajax is a pretty basic combination, so it was not clear.

Comment: @Brian: Most of the time i agree, but parsing without it is just a waste of resources. - And the server is a trusted source, your JS code comes from there anyway.

Comment: `$.ajax` does not necessarily imply that the data returned has been parsed.

Comment: @vbence: hmm... you should probably read up on `JSON.parse()`

Comment: @Brian: The json2 library uses `eval`. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L466

Comment: @jondavidjohn: OP didn't specify what was meant by that. Could have been shown as a String.

Comment: @patrick dw: yes, but only after it sanitizes the string. Thus, `JSON.parse()` > `eval()`

Comment: @Brian: Yeah, I know. That's really the point. There are proper and improper uses of `eval`.

Comment: @Brian: The JSON library is still eval, it only checks for obvious signs of functions thru regex. As a rule of thumb I agree that using eval on unchecked data is bad, but it does not change the fact that is parsed by the eval function.

Comment: As the post was kind of vague, I added a clause for security considerations. Hope no more misunderstandings.