# extracting name and id from json

Tags: java, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to extract id value from this json data. I tried many ways but I don't know what went wrong in my code also I wnt to store id into an array

```
     JSONObject json = readurl("https://graph.facebook.com/"+s);
    System.out.println(json);
    String json2=json.getString("likes");


{"data":[
{
   "id":"**********",
   "name":"skkjghkjhkj"
}, 
{
   "id":"********",
   "name":"khkfjhkjf"
}
]
```

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: @Jhanvi same ques I posted here..but neither of the answers work for me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074192/extracting-json-fields-using-java/22074360?noredirect=1#comment33477332_22074360

Comment: You could use JSON parsers for your language. What error are you getting ? What is your programming language ? Is it Java ? If so you could use Json parsers like 'jackson-mapper-asl'

Comment: The answer that you have accepted in your question works fine, just i guess the use of libraries is improper, include [org-json jar](https://code.google.com/p/org-json-java/downloads/detail?name=org.json-20120521.jar&can=2&q=) and then try.

Comment: @Jhanvi i included it already..but it shows no o/p

Comment: If you're "using" Facebook4J, why are you then parsing the result JSON manually? You could use http://facebook4j.org/javadoc/facebook4j/api/LikeMethods.html#getUserLikes()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure if this is the right answer or maybe I've misread the question, but as said in the question extracting the `id` from `data` could be done by:

`syso(json2.data[i].id)`
`i=0 -> n`

basically your JSON contains an array in it, so you would access it like any other array!

**Source:** [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp) [Stackoveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173603/how-to-access-an-array-in-a-json-object)