# How to handle Ajax JSON response?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm basically doing an Ajax call which returns a dynamic result each time, here's a sample of the response

```
[{"id":10858362988,"http_code":"200","result_code":"1"}]
```

How can I access the `result_code`? I've tried doing the following to no avail

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: window.apiURL,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            var myObj = $.parseJSON(data);
            switch(myObj.result.code) {
                //this doesn't work for some reason???
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: The OP here has an `array`. The link doesn't seem to solve his problem though @CaseyFalk

Comment: Ooooookay... I'd say a comment telling the OP that they can index `data` as a normal array (and then referring them to the related post) would suffice. : / But, fair enough.

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173603/how-to-access-an-array-in-a-json-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the response of the `AJAX GET` Request is an array, you have to access the `key` using `index` as suggested by @tymeJV.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: window.apiURL,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            var myObj = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(myObj[0]["result_code"]);
        }
});
```

If the response is an array of objects:

Something like: `[{"id":10858362988,"http_code":"200","result_code":"1"}, {"id":20858362988,"http_code":"404","result_code":"1"}]`, do something like below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: window.apiURL,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            var myObj = $.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i=0; i<myObj.length; i++) {
                console.log(myObj[i]["result_code"]);
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You would do:

```
var code = myObj[0]["result_code"];
```

You have an array containing 1 object, so reference the index.