# How to bind a JSON array to a second HTTP get operator in angularjs?

Tags: c#, angularjs, json, http

I am trying to acces an array in array in my json object. This is my code to get data:

```
   function activate() {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'Dashboard/GetDashboard'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            var id = $scope.dashboard = response.data;
            var datasource = id.Widgets[1].datasource;
            console.log(datasource);
           // var widgets = tryJsonConvert($scope.dashboard.Widgets);
            $http({
                url: 'Dashboard/GetDataSource/', params: { datasource: datasource },
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(function succesCallback(response) {
                $scope.datasource = response.data.datasource;
            });

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

The `url: 'Dashboard/GetDashboard'` gives me the following json object back:

```
 {  
   "Id":1,
   "UserId":2336276,
   "Name":"Data",
   "Widgets":[  
      {  
         "Id":0,
         "description":"Test1",
         "datasource":"Kri",
         "charttype":"Bar",
         "x":0,
         "y":0,
         "width":3,
         "height":2
      },
      {  
         "Id":0,
         "description":"Test2",
         "datasource":"Kpi",
         "charttype":"Heatmap",
         "x":3,
         "y":0,
         "width":3,
         "height":2
      },
      {  
         "Id":0,
         "description":"Test3",
         "datasource":"Loss events",
         "charttype":"Pie",
         "x":6,
         "y":0,
         "width":3,
         "height":2
      },
      {  
         "Id":0,
         "description":"Test4",
         "datasource":"Loss events",
         "charttype":"Area",
         "x":9,
         "y":0,
         "width":3,
         "height":2
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to acces `datasource` from `widgets` with the second GET operator and get the following error:

[image: Error]

And this is my controller method in C#:

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetDataSource(int id)
    {
        var type = (DataSourceType)id;
        var o = _dashboarBusiness.GetDataSource(type = DataSourceType.KRI);
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
    }
```

I already look at this stack overflow post but it didn't work for me.

[How to access an array in a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173603/how-to-access-an-array-in-a-json-object)

I want to bind the `var datasource` on the param in the URL in the second GET operator.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

UPDATE enum class:

```
public enum DataSourceType
    {
        CONTROL = 1,
        RISK = 2,
        MOI = 3,
        LOSSEVENTS = 4,
        KRI = 5
    }
```

Comment: Change the parameter id in controller to string first. Since you are sending string on second, but controller takes integer argument, so you are getting error.

Comment: Hi Subash thank you for you time. When I changed it to a string I get a error on `var type = (DataSourceType)id;` because I can't cast `DataSourceType` to a string.

Comment: DataSourceType is an enum right?

Comment: Yes I will update my question with the class so you can see it

Comment: Remove var type = (DataSourceType)id; with DataSourceType type ;
Enum.TryParse(id, out type );  Remember it wont work if you are using spaces in id value.

Comment: Nice this did the job! Thank you so much

Comment: mention not bro, just a upvote. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made follwoing changes

1. made int to string

   > [HttpGet]
   >                   public string GetDataSource(string id)
2. `params: { datasource: datasource } to  params: { id: datasource }`